# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer.initHome()

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, nosuchmethoderror

I use JBoss 5.0.1.

I try to deploy some EJB 3.0 beans.

This is my log during JBoss start:

```
 23:19:15,955 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=jboss.j2ee:jndiName=MyServiceFacadeBean/remote,service=EJB state=Configured mode=Manual requiredState=Create
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer.initHome()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer.setupHomeMapping(StatelessSessionContainer.java:132)
at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.createService(SessionContainer.java:168)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:320)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:189)
at $Proxy36.create(Unknown Source)
```

It seems Jboss has incorrect version of required Class or I use some old/new code for EJB deploy.

Please do not tell to use different JBoss version or change my **ejb-jar.xml** I just want to understand where can this class be found?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using one version of JBoss. If you were this would not happen.  The problem is you are using two different and incompatible JBoss libraries and when one calls the other you get this error.

Just make sure you have one version of JBoss.

Comment: And how can I find two incompatible libs?

Comment: If you have a library like jboss-5.0.1 and jboss-4.1 in your class path they will not work together.  You have to be using libraries from a single version of jboss which was compiled together. The error message actually says the class you want is there but doesn't have the method/signature expected.

Comment: But how to find these failure jars?

Comment: Make sure everything in your class path should be there and you are not including an old version which should not be there.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help. I've installed fresh copy of JBoss 5.0.1 and double checked all possible dups/conflicts. Nothing wrong but the error still persist

Comment: If that really is the case, the build is broken. I suggest you use a different version of JBoss.